# Access the body element of a document in an iframe. iframe got the header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, cors

I try to access the content (the body Element) of an iframe from another domain.
I have access to the other domain, so its no problem for me to set headers. I set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` and when I inspect the request in the chrome network I see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in the response header.

But when I try this (JS):

```
//obj = the iframe
obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight
```

I get the following errors:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://mytestdomain" from accessing a frame with origin "http://192.168.0.50". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
```

Do I miss something? 
Why `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` don't work?

Comment: You are mixing up a couple concepts here.  If you want two windows from different domains to exchange information, you must use the [Web Messaging API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-webmessaging-20101118/).  This has nothing to do with the CORS spec.

Comment: You mean something like this: http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/resize-iframe-based-on-content/ ?
The content in the iframe can change and so its height changes. In the like to the easyxdm they say for that I need a `intermediary frame`. But I hope to find another way cause I have access to both servers

Comment: Window 1 needs to post a message to window 2, which must have a registered "message" event handler.  You can read more about this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Comment: @RayNicholus Oh ok. I didn't know Web Massaging. Looks interessting. The only problem I have here is that I have to support IE7..

Comment: You're out of luck then, for the most part.